# SSIS component - Azure Data Lake Store Source failing to load a flat file

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, argument-dependent-lookup

I have got a 9GB file in Azure Data Lake Store. I am trying to load that file data into our local SQL server database. I am using SSIS component " Azure Data Lake Store Source " for this. It is loading partial file and failing in the middle with following error:

> [Azure Data Lake Store Source] Error: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponentHResultException (0xC02090F5): Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC02090F5 from a method call.
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationService.AdlsComponents.PipelineComponentSource.TransferToOutputBuffers(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)"

In order to see if any issues with the file -  I have downloaded the file from ADL store to our local system. Now I created a new package using SSIS component - "Flat File Source". Package is running fine and loading all the data from the file.

Not sure how to find out the error with ADL SSIS Source component. Error message is not that helpful.

Anyone has got any suggestions or thoughts for fixing this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I figured out that delimiter character (",") was present in my input file which got loaded in to ADLS destination.

I removed the delimiter(",") from my input file and loaded the same file to ADLS and retrieved the file with all records successfully.